# Angular Material Progress Spinner: display as overlay

Tags: angular, angular-material

How to display the Angular Material Progress Spinner as a somewhat transparent overlay of the current view (a page or a modal dialog)?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I was inspired by: [Overriding Angular Material Size and Styling of md-dialog-container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46271898/overriding-angular-material-size-and-styling-of-md-dialog-container)

I solved it like this:

## Create a New Component

Create a new component ProgressSpinnerDialogComponent

The content of progress-spinner-dialog.component.html:

```html
<mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
```

The content of progress-spinner-dialog.component.ts:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-progress-spinner-dialog',
  templateUrl: './progress-spinner-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./progress-spinner-dialog.component.css']
})
export class ProgressSpinnerDialogComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

## Add a Style

In styles.css add for @angular/material version 17.x onwards:

```css
.transparent .mat-mdc-dialog-container {
    --mdc-dialog-container-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
}

.transparent .mat-mdc-dialog-surface {
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

for previous versions of @angular/material:

```css
.transparent .mat-dialog-container {
    box-shadow: none;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
}
```

## Use the Component

Here an example usage of the progress spinner:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from "@angular/material/dialog";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { ProgressSpinnerDialogComponent } from "/path/to/progress-spinner-dialog.component";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-use-progress-spinner-component',
  templateUrl: './use-progress-spinner-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./use-progress-spinner-component.css']
})
export class UseProgressSpinnerComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private dialog: MatDialog
  ) {
    let observable = new Observable(this.myObservable);
    this.showProgressSpinnerUntilExecuted(observable);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  myObservable(observer) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      observer.next("done waiting for 5 sec");
      observer.complete();
    }, 5000);
  }

  showProgressSpinnerUntilExecuted(observable: Observable<Object>) {
    let dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ProgressSpinnerDialogComponent> = this.dialog.open(ProgressSpinnerDialogComponent, {
      panelClass: 'transparent',
      disableClose: true
    });
    let subscription = observable.subscribe(
      (response: any) => {
        subscription.unsubscribe();
        //handle response
        console.log(response);
        dialogRef.close();
      },
      (error) => {
        subscription.unsubscribe();
        //handle error
        dialogRef.close();
      }
    );
  }
}
```

**Add it to the app.module**

```
 declarations: [...,ProgressSpinnerDialogComponent,...],
 entryComponents: [ProgressSpinnerDialogComponent],
```

Comment: best answer right here.  You may also want to add the option, "disableClose: true", so that the user can't exit out of it on their own

Comment: @Sharpiro yes, you are right, I will update the answer

Comment: Very good solution, thx!
@toongeorges by the variation with spinner I would add the 'disableClose: true' option too.

Comment: `myObservable = (observer) => {` if using `this.` within **http** **get** / **post** within the observable

Comment: Dialog get transparent color. but still When Dialog full loaded I get the white background, and also the component which is called from dialog, have transparet background color. Angular 16

Comment: @ImIGI the answer only explains how to use a spinner as an overlay. It does not explain how to open another dialog. Another dialog has to be opened with another `dialog.open` call that does not provide `panelClass: 'transparent'`. The content of this dialog may have to be put in a div with the class `mat-body` as in `<div class="mat-body">...</div>`. Also the dialog with the spinner should contain only `<mat-spinner></mat-spinner>`

Answer (score 7):

Use the below code to achieve the opaque:

*HTML*

```
<div style="height: 800px" [class.hide]="show">
   <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="showSpinner()">Show spinner</button>
</div>
<app-spinner [show]="show" [size]="150"></app-spinner>
```

*COMPONENT*

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-spinner',
    template: `
      <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" [style.font-size.px]="size" *ngIf="show"></i>
    `
})
export class SpinnerComponent {
  @Input() size = 50;
  @Input() show = false;
  
  showSpinner() {
    this.show = true;
  }
}
```

*CSS*

```
.hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1whmqh)

Comment: Thank you very much Aravind! I'll test it soon!

Comment: is there any way you could organize the code formatting, I cannot understand the code unfortunately

Comment: I don't understand why there is a template in the component and HTML

Comment: @AlexanderMills the template is the HTML for the `spinner` component; the "HTML" is what contains the `spinner` component.

Answer (score 3):

Based on A bit different approach: Two components, first to open the dialog, second is the dialog. In the component you want to show the spinner just add:

`<app-dialog-spinner *ngIf="progressSpinner"></app-dialog-spinner>`

And control the *ngIf in your logic. Above is all you need to call the spinner so the component stays nice and clean.

Dialog spinner component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';

// Requires a transparent css (panel)id in a parent stylesheet e.g.:
// #DialogSpinnerComponent {
//   box-shadow: none !important;
//   background: transparent !important;
// }

@Component({
  selector: 'app-do-not-use',
  template: `<mat-spinner></mat-spinner>`,
  styles: []
})
export class DialogSpinnerDialogComponent { }

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dialog-spinner',
  template: ``,
  styles: []
})
export class DialogSpinnerComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private dialog: MatDialogRef<DialogSpinnerDialogComponent>;

  constructor(
    private matDialog: MatDialog,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.dialog = this.matDialog.open(DialogSpinnerDialogComponent, { id: 'DialogSpinnerComponent', disableClose: true });
    });
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.dialog.close();
    });
  }

}
```

Declare the components in your module and of course register `DialogSpinnerDialogComponent` in your entryComponents. Add the css properties to a parent stylesheet. This can probably be improved but I'm a bit pressed for time.

Comment: Thank you very much Pimmoz!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work with Angular 13 following Tomek's solution however I had to add: `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` to my  `@Component` declaration that is being used as a dialog:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-progress-spinner-dialog',
  templateUrl: './progress-spinner-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./progress-spinner-dialog.component.css'],
  // this needed to override the mat-dialog-container CSS class
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Without this reference to `ViewEncapsulation.None` I was not able to get the CSS override to work. I found this great hint here: [Learn Angular 11 MatDialog Basics](https://www.developer.com/languages/javascript/angular-11-matdialog-basics/)