# Angular2 : Create generic Loader Service for xhr calls

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to build a small application using angular2 with more reusable components. Here, I want to have a **Loader Service** which gets executed on every **xhr** call.

For that, this is what I came up with

1. **Using Promise**

   ```
   export class SpinnerService {

       showSpinner = false;

       spinnerPromise(observableToWaitFor: Observable<any>, text?: string): Promise<any> {
           this.showSpinner = true;
           return promiseToWaitFor.toPromise()
               .then((data) => { this.showSpinner = false; return data; });
       }   

   }
   ```

   This is how I'm consuming my SpinnerService

   ```
       constructor(private requestService: RequestService, private spinnerService: SpinnerService) { }

       signin(username: string, password: string) {
           let url = _.template(API_Constant.LOGIN)({ username: username });
           return this.spinnerService.spinnerPromise(this.requestService
               .makeRequest(url, RequestMethod.Get))
               .then(data => {
                   let peoples = data.results;
                   let found = _.find(peoples, (p: any) => p.name.toLowerCase() === username.toLowerCase());
                   if (found && found.birth_year === password) {

                   } else {
                       return Promise.reject('Invalid username or password');
                   }
               });
       }
   }
   ```

   It works fine till some extent. But I'm not very well convinced with the usage, as it restrict the *AuthService* to consume *Promise*.
2. Using Observable

   I'm a beginner in using Observable, so I don't know how difficult or easy it is to implement a generic Loader Service.

This is what I tried

```
@Injectable()
export class SpinnerService {

    showSpinner = false;
    public consumer: ReplaySubject<any> = new ReplaySubject(1);

    spinnerPromise(observableToWaitFor: Observable<any>, text?: string) {
        this.showSpinner = true;
        return observableToWaitFor.subscribe(
            response => this.consumer.next(response),
            error => { this.showSpinner = false; },
            () => { this.showSpinner = false; }
        );
    }

}
```

This returns a **Subscription**. But is there a way to **update the *showSpinner* without subscribing it**.

Comment: You can use `.do()` to perform side-effects but this assumes you'll subscribe  to the Observable later anyway.

Comment: @martin what if api call failed, would .do() still get executed?

Comment: `do()` takes three callbacks. For `next`, `error` and `complete` signals so you can choose what you want  to handle.

Comment: Instead of creating it as a service you can create as a custom common component as in this [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42963444/angular-2-material-progress-spinner-display-as-overlay/43243097#43243097)

Comment: @Aravind I already have a component SpinnerComponent which interacts with this SpinnerService which shows/hides the loader.

Comment: you can directly use the component where ever you need to show the spinner. why you use subject and complicate

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working..the only change I had to do, is to use `finally` like this

```
export class SpinnerService {

    showSpinner = false;
    spinnerPromise(observableToWaitFor: Observable<any>, text?: string) {
        this.showSpinner = true;
        return observableToWaitFor.finally(() => this.showSpinner = false);            
    }
}
```